# How Catch WELD-001303 Faces Flow

Tags: jsf-2.2, weld, faces-flow

I'm studying the flow faces and implemented something similar as described in http://en.kodcu.com/2013/08/jsf-2-2-use-faces-flow/ have difficulty after leaving the flow if I use the browser back button and click on a button the previous page I get the exception `WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped`. Does this happen because the flow has already been destroyed?

Is there any possibility of treating this error? Or should I simply redirect to a page when trying to access a view that is no longer an associated flow?