# WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.2, flow-scope

I implement a faces flow for a registration process, but I get this error when I annotate the bean "CreateBn" with @FlowScoped, and when I use CDI: SessionScoped it works:

```
2014-09-01T10:47:58.010+0000|Avertissement: JSF1063 : AVERTISSEMENT ! D�finition d�une valeur 
d�attribut non-s�rialisable dans HttpSession (cl� : 0d4116bdc7f306730f3ea26b84ab:0_flowStack, classe de la valeur : com.sun.faces.flow.FlowHandlerImpl$FlowDeque).
2014-09-01T10:47:58.013+0000|Grave: Error Rendering View[/inscription/inscription.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /inscription/inscription.xhtml @12,60 value="#{createBn.user.email}": org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
```

and here is the bean:

```
@Named
@FlowScoped("inscription")
public class CreateBn implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final String INSCRIPTION_RETURN = "inscription_return";  

private User user;
...
```

and I'm sure that there is no file naming error: flow folder, xxx-flow.xml, xxx-return.xhtml. Help please

Comment: Just for reference, unanswered dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868594/org-jboss-weld-context-contextnotactiveexception-weld-001303-no-active-contexts and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122969/how-catch-weld-001303-faces-flow and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391037/contextnotactiveexception-in-simple-faces-flow-with-cdi

Comment: as you said: Unanswered

Comment: Where's your flow definition?

Comment: got this same problem with ViewScoped

Comment: flow definition is an empty xml file

Comment: [Please see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391037/contextnotactiveexception-in-simple-faces-flow-with-cdi/30453057#30453057) :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it might be fixed by editing your xml config file and place there a code like:

```
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

    <flow-definition id="inscription">
    </flow-definition>
</faces-config>
```

if that not helps, check if you are not context.xml in your WEB-INF folder with content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/PROJEST_NAME"/>
```

I had similar problem but doing one of them or both (i dont rememeber) i had problem solved.

If that was any help (or not), please give a note with was it. I'm trying to learn flows myself and found few obstacles (this was one of them).

Answer (score 0):

Was getting this when i had a graphicImage viewer or documentViewer that binds to a value in a view scoped bean. So I moved the value/contact of what needs to be on the graphicImage viewer and documentViewer to a new managed bean which is session scoped and set cached to false on the graphicviewer. I know it's just a work around but it works pretty well.